# Unable to change the text of UILabel

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uilabel, uitableview

I have two views and the variable is loaded from my TestViewController which is a UITableViewController. Below i have the part of the code where i believe it will be useful.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *selected = [[_sectionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Section"];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.viewController.detailSec = selected;
    NSLog(@"%@",selected);
}
```

At my ViewController the following code is supposed to change my UILabel text to my variable

```
-(void)setDetailSec:(id)newDetailSec {

    if (_detailSec != newDetailSec) {
        [_detailSec release];
         _detailSec = [newDetailSec retain];
        [self configureView];
    }
    NSLog(@"Step 2 %@",_detailSec);
}


-(void)configureView {
   if (self.detailSec) {
       self.detailLabelChord.text = [_detailSec description];
    NSLog(@"Step 3 %@", _detailSec);
}
```

As you can see I added NSLogs in order to check whether the if functions are called and whether the variable changes accordingly and it does! But my UILabel will not change!

```
2012-07-18 22:03:26.077 testapp[17332:11303] Step 3 CHS 21.3x3.2
2012-07-18 22:03:26.078 testapp[17332:11303] Step 2 CHS 21.3x3.2
2012-07-18 22:03:26.079 testapp[17332:11303] Step 1 CHS 21.3x3.2
```

Any ideas or suggestions? I don't know whether i can upload my project if you need more information.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you @synthesize detailLabelChord in the implementation of your View Controller?

Comment: Why are you adding a new Viewcontroller at each selection, could it be that you just can't see the right one because it is overlayed?

Comment: You are most likely losing the reference to `self.detailLabelChord` because you keep resetting `self.viewController`.  I'm guessing `self.detailLabelChord` is a `UILabel` on the `ViewController` nib?

Comment: @Jon Friskics Yes i have synthesized it and referenced it in my .xib

Comment: @iOS where should I add my ViewController? it is the only way i found to transfer the variable in my ViewController if you are talking about "self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];" is there any other way?

Comment: @Justin Paulson can you be more specific? Yes detailLabelChord is a UILabel on the ViewController. I am using the same method as Master-Detail application sample in Xcode and this is the most frustrating part that I am using exactly the same method but it wont work.

Comment: Yes, but may be I do not understand what you want to do. What I understand is that you have two separated views: a master with a label and a tableview list and a detail view according to the selected tableview entry. Whenever you select something from the tableview the detailview should be created/loaded and the label in the masterview should be updated. Is this right?

Comment: I have a master (ViewController) with my UILabel and a UIButton. And a TableView (TestViewController) which popsover upon pressing my button. Once selecting my cell I want my label to change into the Cell content. Do u want me to post both my .h files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *selected = [[_sectionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Section"];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.viewController.detailSec = selected;
    NSLog(@"%@",selected);
}
```

do this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *selected = [[_sectionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Section"];
    self.viewController.detailSec = selected;
    NSLog(@"%@",selected);
}
```

There is no need to initialize a new `viewController` from a nib every time you select a row.  You already have `viewController`.  When you make a new `viewController` you are calling `setDetailSec` on this new controller that hasn't been displayed.  You are not calling it on the `viewController` that you can see with the `UILabel`.

Comment: by removing my ViewController alloc the variable is not called in the ViewController. my log results are. "2012-07-18 22:49:43.373 testapp[18920:11303] Step 1 CHS 21.3x2.3" only.

Comment: did you EVER initialize the `viewController` in your `TestViewController`?  I would initialize the viewController early on and just do it ONCE, not every single time a row is selected.  You are not linking the `viewController` property to the view that is being displayed.  You are just creating a new `viewController` that isn't even being displayed.

Comment: Can you please be more specific on initialize? Sorry for my questions but this isn't my field and this is my first time taking xcode seriously.

Comment: When you use this: `self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];` you are creating a brand new `ViewController` and saving a reference to it as `self.viewController`.  This new `ViewController` is not displayed, it is just sitting there in virtual land and connected to `self.viewController`.  It is the same TYPE as the one you are trying to access with the `UILabel` but it is a totally new copy of it.  You need to make `self.viewController` point to the correct `ViewController` that is being displayed.  How did you create the `ViewController`?

Comment: @class ViewController; in my .h file and property ViewController *viewController. in my .m file i used #import "ViewController.h" and synthesized it. is this the correct way? sorry for posting this way but i can't add as code and i can only use "at" symbol once in this comment.

Comment: I mean the one that is being displayed, how was it created?  Interface builder?  Programmatically?

Comment: I just created a new ipad View Project and added my TestViewController with my xib

Comment: Is there anyway i can send you the project?

Comment: Thank you for your responses! Since it my first time here i don't know how to upvote you please feel free to let me know or how to mark this as answered! The solutioned lied there just like you said. i replace the line with "AppDelegate *appDelegate = 
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];"